# Dialogflow fullfilment on firebase function if ask from telegram

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I wrote function which work on firebase function and which take an answer on request if request come from the dialog console or the Google Assistant emulator. But if I ask from Telegram this function doesn't work.

Answer like `Say that one more time?` or if I filled the form `Responses` on web I have this response.

How connect firebase function with Telegram?

```
'use strict';
const {
  dialogflow,
  Permission,
  Suggestions,
  BasicCard,
} = require('actions-on-google');

const firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
app.intent('simple word', (conv) => {   
        conv.ask(`it's ok`);
});
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code for the function, and possibly some examples of exactly what is working and what isn't?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the code. Now I add the my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that you're using the actions-on-google library, which is specifically designed to send results to the Assistant.

If you want to be able to send results to Telegram, you need to use the [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) library, which handles things slightly differently.